# SQL Server distinct not being used properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select just one account using SQL Server but am getting the following error:

> *ERROR: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because
>   it is not comparable. Error Code: 421*

with the following statement:

```
select DISTINCT ad.*,
       acc.companyname,
       acc.accountnumber
from address ad 
join AddressLink al on al.AddressID = ad.id
join account acc on acc.ID = al.ParentID 
where acc.accountnumber like '11227'
```

What have I done wrong?

### Edit:

New query:

```
select address.ID,
       address.StreetAddress1,
       address.StreetAddress2,
       address.City,
       Address.State,
       Address.PostalCode,
       Address.ClassTypeID,
       account.companyname,
       account.accountnumber,
       addresslink.ID as addressLinkID,
       addresslink.addresstypeid
from address 
join AddressLink on address.id = addresslink.AddressID 
join account  on  addresslink.ParentID = account.ID 
where account.CompanyName like 'company name'
```

[image: returned records]

All the company names that I've had to blur are identical.

Comment: Which column is a `TEXT` type? (something in `address` I assume)

Comment: Also please post a sample of your data.  Are all rows in `address` distinct?

Comment: if you want single data why dont you use TOP afterall you don't have any other criteria that TOP would harm

Comment: @brykneval won't this randomly select one record?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Apparently not. I think I may have some redundancies in my data. I will post sample data in two seconds.

Comment: if any of column is text then try to do CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), column_name) and see if it works

Comment: @thomas it will generate top value depending on your order by is either asc or dsc

Comment: @DMK you can use like on numeric fields, SQL Server will implicitly convert to a varchar for comparison.

Comment: @Tim Lehner Thanks for that, just had a play and ofcourse you're right. For some reason I was of the impression the SQL Server would only implicitly convert integers to a varchar for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select ad.*,
       l.companyname,
       l.accountnumber
from address ad 
join (select DISTINCT al.AddressID,
                      acc.companyname,
                      acc.accountnumber
      from account acc 
      join AddressLink al on acc.ID = al.ParentID 
      where acc.accountnumber like '11227') l
on l.AddressID = ad.id
```

Answer (score 2):

"Distinct", in the context you have is trying to do distinct on ALL columns.  That said, there are some data types that are NOT converable, such as TEXT.  So, if your table has some of these non "Distinctable" column types exists, that is what is crashing your query.

However, to get around this, if you do something like

```
CONVERT( char(60), YourTextColumn ) as YourTextColumn,
```

It should get that for you... at least its now thinking the final column type is "char"acter and CAN compare it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the data types of the columns in the `address` table. My guess is that one or more of them has the data type text, ntext or image.

One of the restrictions of using text, ntext or image data types is that columns defined of these data types cannot be used as part of a SELECT statement that includes the DISTINCT clause.

For what it's worth, the MSDN article for [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) recommends avoiding these data types and use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. You may want to consider changing how that table is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from Mark B shows a subquery (good idea to limit the domain of the DISTINCT) on AddressLink.AddressId, Account.CompanyName, and Account.AccountNumber.

Let me ask this: Does AddressLink allow more than one record to have the same value in the ParentId and AddressId fields?

If not, and assuming that Mark B's answer works, then just remove the DISTINCT because you're never going to get any duplicates inside of that subquery.

Leaving the DISTINCT in causes a performance hit because the DB has to create a temporary table that is either indexed with a btree or a hash and it has to insert every value returned by the subquery into that table to check if it invalidates the uniqueness constraint on those three fields.  Note that the "optimizer" doesn't know that there won't be any dupes... if you tell it to check for DISTINCT, it will check it...  With a btree index this is going to cause O(n log n) work on the number of rows returned; with a hash it would cause O(n) work but who knows how big the constant factor is in relation to the other work you're doing (it's probably larger than everything else you're doing meaning this could make this run half as fast as without the DISTINCT).

So my answer is Mark B's answer without the DISTINCT in the subquery.  Let me know if AddressLink does allow repeats (can't imagine why it would).